# Javascript Tweet Button not linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wonder whats wrong with my tweet button can somebody check my code? the link does not generate the tweet.

check my code here.

http://codepen.io/mochiii/pen/YyqmJP

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tweet-hold a").hide();
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?", function(response){

      $(".quote").html("<p>" + response.quoteText + "</p>");
      $(".author").html("<p>" + response.quoteAuthor + "</p>");
    });
    $(".tweet-hold a").show();
    var tweet="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + response.quoteText;
    if(response.quoteAuthor!==""){
      tweet+=" - " + response.quoteAuthor;
    }
    $(".tweet-hold a").click(function(tweet){
      $(this).attr('href', tweet);

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `response` is not defined. Check console for errors. The scope of `response` is just inside the ajax success.

Comment: yes sir i figured it out already i put the whole tweet code inside the callback function. Thanks helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you need to modify your code a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tweet-hold a").hide();
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?", function(response){

      $(".quote").html("<p>" + response.quoteText + "</p>");
      $(".author").html("<p>" + response.quoteAuthor + "</p>");
    });
    $(".tweet-hold a").show();
    var tweet="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + response.quoteText;
    if(response.quoteAuthor!==""){
      tweet+=" - " + response.quoteAuthor;
    }
  });

  $(".tweet-hold a").click(function(tweet){
      $(this).attr('href', tweet);

   });
});
```

That seemed to work fine, when I tried in your codepen.

Comment: thanks sir i modified the code a bit the problem in my code that i posted is that the var tweet can't access the response.quote*** outside the callback function. Thank you also helped a lot!

Comment: Its mam, not sir... :P ... And you're welcome... That modification actually enabled the click functionality, which earlier wasnt working... :)

Comment: oh im sorry about that. Anyways thanks alot saved me from being stucked :)